# Spring Quartz Always Uses RAM Job Store

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, h2

I am using the following config for my spring + quartz service:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./scheduler.h2;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.quartz.jdbc.commentPrefix=” — “
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=3
```

However, it is always starting with

```
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered
```

what else needs to be done to make quartz use the h2 database instance?

Comment: Please take look at : https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/quartz-h2-jdbcjobstore-example/

Answer (score 1):

To use JDBCJobStore, you first need to set the JobStore class property of your Quartz configuration to be either org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX or org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT

Configuring quartz to use jobstoretx

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
```

Ref: 
https://dzone.com/articles/mule-quartz-connector-how-to-use-jdbc-jobstore-ins

https://www.candlepinproject.org/docs/candlepin/quartz_setup.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```